# Handle hardware "Recents" button on android emulator skin

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, skin

I'm trying to prepare an Android Emulator skin with hardware buttons "Back", "Home" and "Recents", but I cant't find the key binding for the latter.

I've used

```
buttons {
    back {
        image buttonBack.png
        x 706   
        y 1496
    }
    home {
        image buttonHome.png
        x 447
        y 1494
    }
    soft-left {
        image buttonRecents.png
        x 280
        y 1496
    }
}
```

but obviously the "Recents" button act like the old menù button.

What is the correct binding?

Thanks.